# Comic book with nanotech werewolf, earth elemental and chupacabras?

Tags: story-identification, comics

I read this comic back in the mid-90's. It was probably from one of the smaller, independent publishers of the time. Full color printing. Either it never concluded or I was never able to fid the final issues.

The plot:
A retired paranormal special ops guy comes out of retirement to join a team of weird creatures who are hunting down a dangerous demon.

The characters:

1. The main human character is a middle aged but still tough-looking white guy. As the story opens he's living in a cabin in the woods and the werewolf woman, his former partner, visits to try and convince him to join the demon hunters. He's reluctant at first, but eventually agrees (pretty standard "one last mission" plot set-up).
2. A female werewolf who's a still active agent. She was the guy's former partner and it's implied they still have a thing for each other. She's got a darker skin tone and curly black hair. At some point she was given a metallic gold colored "nanotechnology" armor that changes shape along with her. It's a sort of skin-tight liquid, so she changed into a golden wolf.
3. An "earth elemental". The actual creature is some sort of spirit, and it constructs its body from the stones, dirt and plants at the place where it manifests, so it always looks slightly different. It's usually a very large humanoid, and I recall it as being somewhat childlike or naive, at any rate inexperienced.
4. A small demon which I believe called itself a chupacabras - at any rate, it spoke with a Speedy Gonzales style "accent". It was dark red or brown with white hair, about three feet tall, resembled a scrawny, clawed and horned humanoid creature with a tail (pretty much basic devil). It smelled bad, so the team nicknamed it Stinky.

There were other members of the group, I think, but I don't recall them.

The antagonist was a demon who was building some sort of interdimensional gate, I think out of skulls or corpses, for some nefarious reason. At one point the werewolf woman and possibly the other non-human members of the team are captured and are to be added to the gate.

It was a large, hunched over creature with thick legs and a tail, small humanlike arms (possibly multiple arms), reddish skin, a long neck sticking straight out parallel to the ground and covered in stringy black hair like a horse's mane, tied in small ribbons, and wearing a mask over it's tiny head that looked like a antique porcelain baby doll face. I remember it was a vain creature, preening in a hand mirror, and at one point it's mask was removed or broken to show it's true, horrible face and it became enraged.